# How to speed up this cypher query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
match (s:Product {type:'Phone'})-[r]->(o:Attributes {Resolution:'2000'}) return s, o limit 2
```

This query takes 15832 ms and times out in my application. My application has a time limit on the time spent on each query. Is there a way to speed up this process? The reason for being slow is because the "Product" node has lots of instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have created an [index](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.3/cypher/schema/index/#schema-index-create-a-single-property-index) on `:Product(type)`, like this:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Product(type);
```

That index will speed up the lookup of all `Product` nodes with a specified `type` value.

Or, if there are relatively few `Attributes` nodes with any given  `Resolution` value, you could add an index on `:Attributes(Resolution)` instead, and provide a hint to use that index 
 (if you also have an index on `:Product(type)`):

```
MATCH (s:Product {type:'Phone'})-->(o:Attributes {Resolution:'2000'})
USING INDEX o:Attributes(Resolution)
RETURN s, o
LIMIT 2
```

Comment: I already have an index on that. Even that, if I have tens of millions of products for a 'type', it still takes lots of time to search through the list of millions of products. Right?

Comment: This new query only times 1 ms. That's too great!

Comment: can you explain why it speed up so much? Isn't that it still needs to search through all the Product instances?

Comment: Once the handful of matching `Attributes` nodes are found via the index, neo4j just needs to follow the relationships from those few nodes and test the `Product` nodes on the other end.